# WCF Data Services and Relationships in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, wcf-data-services

Recently I have been working with WPF Applications that interact with server through Web Services. I am currently try to use Telerik OpenAccess to works with the database and create services for my WPF application.

However there's one problem I need to resolve and some how I can't get it to work.

The relationships in database doesn't seem to works.

I've tried to use `WCF Endpoint Service` and `Data Service for .Net 4`. Both have function to create a record to database like this:

```
service.createRecord(Record x)
```

My database relationship is simply have a Many to Many model like ff:

```
--------------
RecordID
--------------
 1
 2
 3

---------------
RecordTag
---------------
RID   |  TID  |
---------------
  1       1
  2       1
  3       1
---------------

---------------
Tag
---------------
TID 
---------------
  1
  2
  3
```

In my code, I did the ff:

```
Service.Record r = new Service.Record(){  [...] };
r.Tags.Add(new Service.Tag(){ [...] };
```

Result is:
1. WCF Endpoint Service`doesn't able to add Tags because r was null.
2.`Data Service for .Net 4`was only add`Record` without any Tags

Anyone know how to solve this problem? Any answer or hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the WCF Data Services case, just setting the proeprty is not enough. You need to let the context know that you want to add a link (relationship). This is because the entities do not perform property level tracking.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756361.aspx
Especially the part about relationship links.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you can't get Record back on client? if so, have you use DataContractAttribute on your data (Record etc.) in your endpoint service?